# forEach loop skips modal opening

Tags: javascript

I have an array with n amount of words. I am running a forEach loop to go through each element, for each one it should open a modal with a text input, and after clicking a button, the value is stored in a new array and the modal goes away. Then the same should happen n amount of times.

I had tested it with prompt and it worked fine. I am console logging the value in the loop and what seems to be happening is each word in the array gets logged, THEN the modal opens only for the last instance. Not sure why

Here is the for each loop:

```
words.forEach(function(word) {

      console.log(word);

      $('.modal-title').html("Edit value for "+word);
      $('#wordModal').modal('show');

      $('#submit').click(function() {

        let input = $('#elm2').val();

        newBody = body.replaceAll("["+word+"]", input);
        body = newBody;

        $('#wordModal').modal('hide');
      })
    });
```

When the modal appears the title says "Enter value for (last element in the array)"

My goal:

For each element in the array, I would like a pop-up to appear on the screen to change the value of it. The load another pop up for the next element so on and so forth. So far prompt works fine but doesn't look nice.

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="wordModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Value</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Comment</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="elm2" placeholder=""></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The code is behaving exactly they way it should.  You are looping and making the same model visible so it one model updated for every word and hence you see the last word only. You need to show the mode wait for the input and then show it for the second word once the first one is captured.

Comment: A modal is not the same as a javascript prompt or alert. Prompts and alerts halt the execution of javascript until the user clicks on a button. A modal is just html. It doesn't halt javascript. If you want the same behaviour, you have to take a different approach. Like a function instead of a loop.

Comment: but why do You expect it to go one after another ? I mean the code won't wait for click 
the `click` method only attaches the listener with callback function nothing more. And then processes next object. You should make it more like linked list, on item change in the callback.

Comment: I was unaware modals didnt halt javascript. Does anyone have any examples of alternatives?

Comment: Not without more context. Comments do not have enough space to give you any example. Answers cannot be used unless they _answer_ your question. A random example is not an answer to your question. You'll have to edit your question, add an explanation of what you are trying to do (I mean what the script does for the user, not the problem itself) and add the relevant HTML code as well so we can give you an answer that will actually solve your problem.

Comment: Edited, with modal code and what i want to happen

Comment: The answer here may well depend on which library you're using to open your modal.

Comment: Opinion: Modals should be the execption, not the rule. If you need to do this for n items, then opening n modals is a bad approach to begin with, IMHO. From a user perspective, I would much rather be presented with _one_ form with n input fields, rather than having to interact with n modals one after the other.

Comment: @04FS This is a good suggestion, but i dont want to leave the page so could i use one modal and have the form with n inputs in that one modal?

Comment: @Jamiec `$('#modal').modal('show')`

Comment: @CíanMacTiarnáin thats not an answer to the question I asked. `modal` is not AFAIK native to jquery, you must be using an external library for that and they all subtly differ in their functionality

Comment: @Jamiec Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact this might not be the best UX, the way to do this with modals is to turn the inherently async operation into something which feels more synchronous using `async`/`await`:

```js
function showModal(word){
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  $('.modal-title').html("Edit value for "+word);
  $('#wordModal').modal('show').on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
     let input = $('#elm2').val();
     resolve(input);
  });
 });
}


async function promptAllWords(words){
   for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
      var word = words[i];
      var userResponse = await showModal(word);
      console.log("finished",word,"user typed:",userResponse);
   }
}

promptAllWords(["Hello","World","foo","bar"]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="wordModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Value</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Comment</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="elm2" placeholder=""></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you've commented you want to return something from `promptAllWords` but it returns a Promise, you just need to treat it like it is - an asynchronous call.

```js
async function promptAllWords(words){
   // fluff removed for brevity
   return "Test";
}

promptAllWords().then(result => {
    console.log("return value=",result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, should i put this inside the for each ?

Comment: No, you need to get rid of all that completely and use a standard `for` loop as per my example in the `promptAllWords` method.

Comment: Thank you! I realise it's not the most UX friendly way but it can get me by for now

Comment: I am trying to get the function promptAllWords to return a variable. But it returns a promise? How can i get the variable from that?

Comment: @CíanMacTiarnáin what variable do you want it to return?